# Found nil while unwrapping optional - setting label text in Swift 4

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

I have the following code using Facebook's Swift API:

```
        let displayName = user.displayName

        print(displayName)

        self.nameLabel.text = displayName
```

The displayname variable is printed correctly but when it reaches the last line, I get `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. But displayName has a value?

Comment: Change the last line to 'self.nameLabel?.text = displayName' and see if it still fails. If it does not, then nameLabel is nil.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to nameLabel being nil. Make sure the IBOutlet is connected properly.
If the nameLabel can be nil, avoid the crash using this:

```
self.nameLabel?.text = displayName
```